# Parity keeps restarting warp restore

Tags: parity, bug, warp-sync

It seems to be making progress in the Web UI and it shows in the bottom right, "70% warp restore, Homestead, 1/26/50 peers". After about 70%, it seems to encounter an error and restarts the warp restore. In console, parity prints out the following and then starts "syncing snapshots" from 0/313 again. It always gets to about 160 and then restarts.

```
2017-06-18 17:59:45 UTC Syncing snapshot 160/313    #59186    3/26/50 peers   156 MiB db    3 MiB chain  0 bytes queue    9 MiB sync  RPC:  0 conn,  0 req/s, 195 µs
2017-06-18 17:59:50 UTC Encountered error during block restoration: Block error (Block has invalid PoW: Value 0 out of bounds. Min=735388763471630)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: which version of parity do you use?

Comment: latest master version

Comment: Try stable one? 1.5.12

Comment: I get the same error with Parity 1.6.8.

Comment: Can you confirm which network you are on? Foundation or Classic?

Comment: I have same problem below the error massage.
Do you have a solution?
Anyone help us. 2017-06-19 19:19:37 Syncing snapshot 0/313 #71090 3/12/25 peers 180 MiB db 171 KiB chain 0 bytes queue 10 KiB sync RPC: 1 conn, 8 req/s, 595 µs 2017-06-19 19:19:33 Encountered error during block restoration: Block error (Block has invalid PoW: Value 0 out of bounds. Min=735388763471630)

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/issues/5871#issuecomment-309488346

Answer (score 2):

Many times it is a time-syncing issue

Go to http://time.is/ and ensure it says "Your time is exact":

1-2 seconds out of sync is enough to disrupt peer discovery.

Synchronize your OS clock with the NTP server you are using, so that you see the "Your time is exact" message in the above link.

Make sure your network does not block outgoing UDP traffic (used for NTP synchronization )

taken from : https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/FAQ#what-can-i-do-when-parity-has-trouble-getting-in-sync